# Are the present and future imperative used together?

Tags: imperative, future-tense

Both the usual present imperative (e.g. *fac*) and the future imperative (e.g. *facito*) are attested.
But are they ever used together so that the tenses are contrasted?

In terms of a concrete example, are orders like the following found in the literature?
Or is there something else that suggests that such constructions are valid or invalid?

> *Abi, redito!*
> Go, but come back later!

Comment: Is there a rule on imperatives requiring an accusative e.g. "te abi"? How does the reader know if the receiver is a singular or plural entity?

Comment: @tony The number of the addressee is indicated by the number of the imperative: *abi(to)* for one person, *abi(to)te* for several. An accusative is used for a direct object just like with any other use of the verb; I don't think there's anything special about the imperative.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

In Allen & Greenough p.284; section 449 (Imperative Mood):

> "Phyllida mitte mihi, meus est natalis, Iolla; cum faciam vitula pro frugibus, ipse venito" (Ecl. 3.76);

> "Send Phyllis to me, it is my birthday, Iollas; when I [shall] sacrifice a heifer for the harvest, come yourself."

Therefore, "mitte" for the present tense imperative; "venito", the future.

> "dic quibus in terris, etc. [sic], et Phyllida solus habeto." (id. 3.107);

> "tell in what lands etc., and have Phyllis for yourself."

Similarly, "dic"--present; "habeto"--future.

Comment: Good find. I wonder how common this is in prose.

Answer (score 5):

The following is found in the writings of [Bernardino Stefonio](https://books.google.com.br/books?id=jyKOecTYMN0C&pg=PA365&lpg=PA365&dq=%22abi,%20requirito%22&source=bl&ots=4tGlW9owm2&sig=ACfU3U1TN6Rdm0ISrY-qHAFh9hnjiHYuRw&hl=en&sa=X&ved=2ahUKEwiBz4GOzYXxAhVhLLkGHcbQA0EQ6AEwAHoECAQQAw#v=onepage&q=%22abi%2C%20requirito%22&f=false):

> abi: requirito hominem ubi ubi est.

Comment: Why two "ubi" next to each other?

Comment: @FlatAssembler - According to [L&S](http://www.perseus.tufts.edu/hopper/morph?l=ubi&la=la#lexicon): "Repeated _ubi ubi_, also written as one word _ubiubi_, wherever, wheresoever = _ubicumque_"